# How can I dissolve my Copper(II)sulfate in my MOPS buffer pH 7.2?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

For my research project I need to analyze a copper-ligand complexes in a basic buffer through UV-Vis spectroscopy. After testing several buffers, I currently use the [MOPS buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOPS) which I want to adjust to a pH of around 7.3

The problem is: my copper(II)-ion reacts with almost everything by becoming a hard soluable solid! I have now prepared the MOPS Buffer and adjusted the pH with NaOH (1M) to 7.2 and when I wanted to dissolve my $\ce{CuSO4}$ in it, and it once again resulted in a blue precipitation. I am now at a loss of options since I also get blue precipitation with carbonates, phosphates, ammonia and citrate. Does anybody have insight into what i can do?

structure of MOPS / 3-(*N*-morpholino)propanesulfonic acid:

[image]

(image credit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOPS))

PS:

- adding a chelation agent is also not a useful option since it will compete with the ligand i need to research
- The concentration of the copper(II)-solution is about 40 µM

Comment: Whatever the nature of the buffer, it will react with copper ions

Comment: Did you exhaust [Good's list of buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%27s_buffers?

Comment: The point is, copper ions form insoluble copper hydroxide or many insoluble salts at neutral/alkalic pH, UNLESS there is already present a strong ligand binding itself to copper ions.

Comment: I choose the MOPS because it doesn't interact with any metal ions, especially not copper.

Yes, i did exhaust Good's list of buffers. 

There is a lot of literature with the use of the MOPS Buffer for Copper-Ion research, but (and that is the main problem right now) my Buffer has to be adjustet by adding a Base. In the Literature it says to add NaOH, but this just doesn't work (the blue precipitation)... now i am at a loss of options and ideas with what i can adjust the pH with. NaOH, KOH and Ammonium certainly do not work.

Comment: Ammonium *might* work, since it forms a strong bond with copper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraamminecopper(II)_sulfate . If that interferes, raising the temp might work, for just 40 µM of Cu++.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! in my head i had the notion, that the tetraamminecopper(II)-complex was unsolvable in water, so i guess i will conduct a test tomorrow. A milestone would be reached if i at least get a clear solution in alkalic pH.

Comment: How did you try to dissolve the $\ce{CuSO4}$? It might be the case that precipitation occurred due to high local concentrations.

Comment: UPDATE: ok guys so, thanks for all your help, it really helped get a clear thought about this problem. I have now, at least for this moment, found a solution to my problem. I have set up the MOPS Buffer and adjustet the pH with L-Arginin. It also forms a complex with copper according to literature, but it is fully watersoluable. When analysing the copper solution in the UV-Vis, the copper solution only showed absorbance around 680 nm, which is totally fine since i dont need that wavelength anyway :)
My next alternative would have been to try ammonium acetate to adjust the pH.